# Why is API Gateway body null?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

having an awful time with api gateway today. completely stopped working and now having to write in a different way which makes no sense

when I do this it's fine

```
        fetch(myUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: 'hello working',
        })
```

but when I do this:

```
        fetch(myUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: object OR JSON.stringify(object),
        })
```

it comes through as null???? how can I send an object?

Comment: Have you validated object and the evaluation of object OR JSON.stringify(object)

Comment: yes when I log it, it comes back as `"{"userid": "asidnasdi"}"`

Comment: Check whether you have configured lambda as "Lambda Integration" or "Lambda Proxy Integration" based on that you need to pass parameters.

Comment: If it's Lambda proxy integration then `JSON.stringify()` is correct. You can check data by `JSON.parse(event.body)`